# Python: writing integers to a single byte

Tags: python, struct

I am trying to write 4 integers to a single byte.

In the example below is I can unpack \x11 and then read the bits (answer = 1 2 0 0) but how would I do the reverse? i.e. how would I pack 1 2 0 0 into \xll

```
import struct

val = struct.unpack('B', '\x11')[0]

a = val & 7
b = (val >> 3) & 7
c = (val >> 6) & 1
d = (val >> 7)

print a, b, c, d
```

I am pretty new to all this... many thanks!

Comment: But you know that way you can only store values  a - 3bit, b - 3bit, c - 1bit, d - 1bit? So ranges are a<0,7>, b<0,7>, c<0,1>, d<0,1>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
val = ((d & 1) << 7) | ((c & 1) << 6) | ((b & 7) << 3) | (a & 7)
```